# Aggergate dataframe using dictionary mapping for pivot table

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I would like to efficiently transform a dataframe `df` of the below structure

| country | sector | production |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | automotive | 100 |
| US | aviation | 50 |
| CA | automotive | 30 |
| CA | aviation | 15 |
| JP | automotive | 95 |
| JP | aviation | 25 |

using the mapping (avilable as dictionary `mapping_dict`)

| region | countries |
| --- | --- |
| region_1 | US, CA |
| region_2 | US, JP |

into the aggregated pivot-table of the form

|  | region_1 | region_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| automotive | 115 | 195 |
| aviation | 1200 | 1400 |

without using loops. Before using `pivot`, I tried to aggregate by using the dictionary and `map`, but this won't work due to countries belonging to multiple regions.

```
df['country'] = df['country'].map(mapping_dict)
```

MWE input data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "country": ['US', 'US', 'CA', 'CA', 'JP', 'JP'],
        "sector": ['automotive', 'aviation', 'automotive', 'aviation', 'automotive', 'aviation'],
        "production": [100, 50, 30, 15, 95, 25]
    }
)
dict_country_per_region = {'region_1': 'US, CA', 'region_2': 'US, JP'}
```

Comment: your totals in the expected result don't seem to be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new dataframe for the region-country relation, then merge, and `groupby().sum().unstack()` or `pivot_table`:

```
# if you don't already have the dataframe
regions = pd.DataFrame(list(dict_country_per_region.items()), columns=['region','country'])

# split the country strings, then explode
regions = regions.assign(country=regions['country'].str.split(', ')).explode('country')

(df.merge(regions, on='country')
   .groupby(['region','sector'])['production'].sum()
   .unstack('region', fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
region      region_1  region_2
sector                        
automotive       130       195
aviation          65        75
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#create a dataframe from the dictionary
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict_country_per_region, orient='index', columns=['country'])

#split the list values into rows for easy mapping
df2=df2['country'].str.replace(r'\s','',regex=True).str.split(',').apply(list).explode().reset_index()
df2

#merge
df=df.merge(df2,
        on='country',
        how='left')

df.pivot_table(index='sector', columns='index', values='production', aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

```
index   sector     region_1     region_2
0       automotive      130        195
1       aviation         65         75
```